# React-Native Map subScribeLocationChanges()

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

I was using **RNLocation.subscribeToLocationUpdates** working very well in **Xcode 11.2.1 iOS 13.3 MacOS 10.15.4**

after some days. I am update the OS and run build in
**Xcode 12.0 IOS 14 MacOS Version 10.15.6**
getting location once and it is not giving me updated location
it is being called once after start after that It do not called

> RNLocation.subscribeToLocationUpdates((locations) => { // this give me locations one time only, })

I also have reported this in repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/timfpark/react-native-location/issues/148)